# Question regarding matrix differentiation and matrix/function multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \text {Mat}_{n,n}(\mathbb C)$ and $r: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is a differentiable function given by $t \mapsto r(t)$.

In a book it is written $r(t)A$, so $r(t)$ like a complex number (it has to be otherwise the scalar multiplication is undefined).

Suppose we differentiate $r(t)A$ (entry-wise), then the book states $(r(t)A)'=r'(t)A$. But why are the entries differentiated not all zero? They are all constants?

Also suppose we write $r(t)Av$ where $v \in \text {Mat}_{n,1}(\mathbb C)$. Then if $r(t)$ is a function then all entries of $v$ has to be functions also? We can multiply two functions, but not a function by a scalar? But all entries of $v$ are scalars and also $r(t)$ since we can multiply it by $A$?

Can someone clarify this to me?

Answer (score 1):

You can always multiply functions with scalars and the like. If $f(x)$ is a scalar function, then so is $2\cdot f(x)$. In the same way you can multiply matrices and vectors like your $r \cdot A \cdot v$. Each of the terms may or may not depend on $t$. If you want to, you can also think of $A$ and $v$ as constant functions.

The only thing you need to look after is that the dimensions of matrices and vectors fit together, for example for $v\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ the Product $Av$ only makes sense if $n=m$.

Considering $r(t)A$ you need to think of the product rule. So you would end up with $(r(t)A)' = r'(t) A + r(t) A' = r'(t)A$ since as you said yourself, $ A' = 0 $ since $A$ is constant.

Comment: Formally only functions can be multiplied ? We have to regard a constant as a constant function ?